# Identifying a LC oscillator circuit and solving resonance frequency

Tags: oscillator, passive-networks

Could someone please identify what type of oscillator this is in the first stage. I'm not quite sure if it is a Colpitts or not and also could someone specify the resonance frequency calculation if it is possible?

[image]

Comment: Looks like common-base Colpitts, with FM modulation. With missing data on  L1, frequency is unknowable, but it is probably FM broadcast band. Its frequency is changed with the 10k variable resistor R1.

Comment: yes it's in the FM broadcast band, though even without exact value of L1, is it possible to formulate a general resonance frequency equation of this circuit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a generic AC model* of a Colpitts oscillator that matches yours**.  The tank circuit is formed by the series combination of C3 and C4, in parallel with Cextra and L1.  In your case, Cextra is the series combination of C5 and the diode capacitance (which varies with voltage).  C6 and the following stage complicates things -- that stage's input impedance is *probably* high enough to not matter, but if it's between about \$300\Omega\$ and \$50\Omega\$ then it could pull the frequency down (and reduce the Q of the oscillator).

So, calculate the overall capacitance, then calculate the resonant frequency given L1 (which you don't know), and that's your tank circuit's resonant frequency.  Hopefully the oscillator is designed well enough that the oscillator runs close to the tank circuit's resonant frequency.

* "AC model" meaning that I'm ignoring the bias networks.

** I left it ungrounded on purpose -- you can ground any point on that circuit and it's still a Colpitts; the only thing that changes is where you pick off the output signal, and how hard it is to bias.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI4Z6Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

the oscillator will not oscillate, unless you do this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY2i5Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note the VDD bypass capacitor is a key component of the circulating-resonant-current loop. Thus that cap should be low-loss, and that VDD should be isolated from trash-generating circuitry by a small resistor.